# SQL error in php live support

Tags: php

What is my problem?
After running this I received this error:

> mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be
>   removed in 
>       the enter code here`future: use mysqli or PDO instead - [ SOLUTION CHECKER 
>       DISABLED]
>       enter code here`File Name : /phplive.php
>       File Line #   : 10
>
> phplive.php file:

```
/* (c) OSI Codes Inc. */
    /* http://www.osicodesinc.com */
    /* Dev team: 615 */
    if ( !is_file( "./web/VERSION.php" ) ) { touch( "./web/VERSION.php" ) ; }  
    // patch 4.2.105 adjustment
    include_once( "./web/config.php" ) ;
    include_once( "$CONF[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/API/Util_Format.php" ) ;
    include_once( "$CONF[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/API/Util_IP.php" ) ;
    include_once( "$CONF[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/API/Util_Security.php" ) ;
    include_once( "$CONF[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/API/Util_Error.php" ) ;
    /* AUTO PATCH */
    if ( !is_file( "$CONF[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/web/patches/$patch_v" ) )
    {
        $query = ( isset( $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] ) ) ? $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] : "" ;
        HEADER( "location: patch.php?from=chat&".$query ) ;
        exit ;
    }
    include_once( "$CONF[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/API/Util_Upload.php" ) ;
    include_once( "$CONF[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/API/SQL.php" ) ;
    include_once( "$CONF[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/API/Depts/get.php" ) ;
    include_once( "$CONF[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/API/Ops/get.php" ) ;
    include_once( "$CONF[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/API/Ops/get_itr.php" ) ;
    include_once( "$CONF[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/API/Chat/get_itr.php" ) ;
    include_once( "$CONF[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/API/Marketing/get.php" ) ;
    include_once( "$CONF[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/API/Footprints/remove.php" ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As said on the [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) and on your error message :

> **Warning**
>
> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP
>   7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
>   information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> ```
> mysqli_connect()
> PDO::__construct()
> ```

You're using an outdated way to connect to your Database, you'll need to switch to PDO ou `mysqli_*` function